# Update another column if specific column exist on updation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

I have a model which have two columns `admin_approved` and `approval_date`. Admin update `admin_approved` by using `activeadmin`. I want when admin update this column `approval_date` also update by current_time.

I cant understand how I do this.Which `call_back` I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_update 'self.approval_date = Time.now', if: "admin_approved?"
 end
```

This assumes you have `admin_approved (bool)` and `approval_date (datetime)` in your table.

The way it works is to [use a string](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Types+of+callbacks) to evaluate whether the `admin_approved` attribute is "true" before update. If it is, it sets the `approval_date` to the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `after_save` callback inside your model.

It would be something like this:

```
after_save do
  if admin_approved_changed?
    self.approval_date = Time.now
    save!
  end
end
```

Or change the condition as you like!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the approval_date before your model instance will be saved. So you save a database write process instead of usage of after_save where you save your instance and in the after_save callback you would save it again.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_approval_date

  # ... your model code ...

  private

  def set_approval_date
    if admin_approved_changed?
      self.approval_date = Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

May be in your controller:

```
my_instance = MyModel.find(params[:id])
my_instance.admin_approved = true
my_instance.save
```